# Recover files from non-booting FDE system

Tags: 18.04, encryption, data-recovery

My full disk encrypted Ubuntu 18.04 installation only shows a black screen after requiring the encryption key, probably because I messed up some libraries. Before formatting and reinstalling, I need to recover a couple files that were in the `home` folder. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in my case, I was able to access the system using tty1 (or any other non-GUI interface) by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and from there I could copy my files via command line to an external hard drive.